# Socket.ReceiveLenght subtraindo 4 bytes

Tags: delphi

Boa noite pessoal,

estou com problemas na parte do recebimento do arquivo que é o seguinte:

o arquivo é enviado corretamente para a aplicação servidor com todo o conteúdo original, acontece que quando estou debugando a aplicação servidor com breakpoint e coloco um

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Socket.ReceiveLenght));
```

, se o conteúdo original que chegou do arquivo txt tem por exemplo 251 bytes, a mensagem me retorna o tamanho exato (251) até aí tudo bem!, já quando eu atribuo

**Socket.ReceiveLenght** a variável *curSize* (parte Servidor) o debug me informa que foi atribuído apenas 247 bytes de conteúdo.

Já não sei mais onde mexer nesse código. Alguém poderia me dá uma ideia onde eu estou errando?

Segue abaixo o código de envio e recebimento respectivamente.

```
// Código que envia o arquivo (aplicativo cliente)

var 

fs: TFileStream; 
size: integer; 
foname:string; 

begin 

foname:= 'c:\arquivo.txt'; 

   fs := TFileStream.Create(foname, fmOpenRead); 

try 
  size := fs.Size; 
  CS1.Socket.SendBuf(size, sizeOf(size)); 
  CS1.Socket.SendStream(fs); 
except 
  fs.Free; 
  exit; 
end; 

end; 


//Código que recebe o arquivo (aplicativo servidor)

var 

  fSize: integer = -1; 
  fs: TFileStream = nil; 

        procedure TForm1.SSLClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket); 
        var 
        curSize: integer; 
        buf: pointer; 
        myDate: TDateTime; 
        myYear, myMonth, myDay: Word; 
        myHour, myMin, mySec, myMilli: Word; 

        begin 

        myDate := Now; 
        DecodeDateTime(myDate, myYear, myMonth, myDay, myHour, myMin, mySec, myMilli); 
        if Socket.ReceiveLength = 0 then 
        exit; 

        if fSize = -1 then 
        begin 
        Socket.ReceiveBuf(fSize, sizeOf(integer)); 
        end; 

        fs := TFileStream.Create('arquivo' + ' --- ' + IntToStr(myHour) + '-' + IntToStr(myMin) + '-' + IntToStr(MySec) + '.txt', fmCreate); 
        curSize := Socket.ReceiveLength; // aqui é onde está o problema 

        while curSize > 0 do 
        begin 
        if curSize + fs.Size > fSize then 
        curSize := fs.Size - fSize; 
        GetMem(buf, curSize); 
        try 
        curSize := Socket.ReceiveBuf(buf^, curSize); 
        if curSize <> - 1 then 
        begin 
        fs.Write(buf^, curSize); 
        end; 
        finally 
        FreeMem(buf); 
        end; 

        if (fs.Size = fSize) then 
        begin 
        fSize := -1; 
        fs.Free; 
        fs := nil; 
        Application.ProcessMessages; 
        if Socket.ReceiveLength = 0 then 
        begin 
        end; 
        end; 
        break; 
        end; 

        curSize := Socket.ReceiveLength; 
        end; 

 end;
```